# Problems with dict+zip of a list - losing first two values of the list in the conversion?

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

How is testList being handled differently that myShortList?! Notice the output of testList is MISSING 2 values of the 'testList' when placed into the dict! Please HELP!

```
>>> testList
['1', 'targets', '0', 'alive', '1', 'unreachable']
>>> myShortList
['254', 'targets', '12', 'alive', '242', 'unreachable']
>>> dict(zip(myShortList[::2], myShortList[1::2]))
{'254': 'targets', '12': 'alive', '242': 'unreachable'}
>>> dict(zip(testList[::2], testList[1::2]))
{'1': 'unreachable', '0': 'alive'}
```

Comment: `testList` has duplicate keys, which you can't have in a dict.

Answer (score 1):

A python dictionary has to have unique keys. In testList you are asigning key "1" to value "targets" and then you asign key "1" to value "unreachable". This overwrites your initial "targets" value and leaves you with only two entries.

A better format would be to have the words ["targets", "alive", "unreachable"] as your keys and then they each have a value. The values do not have to be unique and this also allows you to easily retrieve values from the dictionary.

```
test_dict = dict(zip(testList[1::2], testList[::2]))
print(test_dict["targets"])  # Returns "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in Python, dict should have keys as unique and immutable, in your last example, you were trying to add keys with same value and hence, it overwrote the first one.

Print this:

```
print(list(zip(testList[::2], testList[1::2])))
```

Output:

```
[('1', 'targets'), ('0', 'alive'), ('1', 'unreachable')]
```